# Idea don't compile some modules

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have big project. When I run it (make and build artifacts) deploy fails cause of ClassNotFoundException (in target/classes in some modules does not exist package with compiled sources). How can I fix it?

Comment: Find your class location and make sure it's folder marked as source directory. Modify project setting to be sure that your module included in project.

Comment: @mst yes, it is source directory. Module is included. If I run mvn clean install (or compile), then idea swears on duplicate classes. Now I run only wars created by maven, but I need hot swap and fast recompile using idea, because maven compile it so long.

Comment: I tried invalidate cache, invalidate cache and restart, change branch. Now I am trying to mvn idea:clean and reimport project to idea.